# Importing Media IDs but not related attachment

Tags: media, media-library, import

When importing media to a live site that was exported from a local environment, I tried uploading the uploads folder to a temporary location and then updated the XML to the new paths. It worked for a few images, but fails every time after just a few images. Is there a way to import just the Media ID so that the database knows the images exist, and then manually upload the uploads folder to wp-content?

Comment: XML and the WordPress database are not related.

Comment: The XML points to paths where the media can be found since it can't find it on the local dev environment. It has worked for some people to do it that way but doesn't seem to work all of the time.